# ¿Cómo navegar usando el Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, navigation

Tengo 3 fragments y una activity. En el fragment 2 tengo 2 botones uno para avanzar y otro para retroceder, el de avanzar funciona bien. El problema es: Cómo hago para que los 2 botones funcionen correctamente; el de avanzar y el de retroceder? Si notan tengo una acción extra que sale del fragment 2 con la id de volver, supuse que ayudaría el hacerlo.

```
package com.example.navigation

class Fragmento2 : Fragment() {

private var _binding: FragmentFragmento2Binding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    _binding = FragmentFragmento2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}   

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.btnIrpantalla3.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.next_action)
        }
    }

}
```

Aquí el cómo están en el nav graph

[image: Aquí el cómo están en el nav graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la misma forma, usando el id de la acción que creaste

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.btnIrpantalla3.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.next_action)
    }
    binding.btnRetroceder.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.volver)
    }
}
```

pero recuerda agregarle atributo [popUpTo](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack) a las acciones porque sino se irán agregando al back stack y tendrás fragments duplicados.

Una mejor solución podría ser usar el método `popBackStack()`. Este siempre navega al fragment anterior eliminando el fragment actual del back stack, por lo que no necesitarías crear una acción ni preocuparte por los duplicados.

```
binding.btnRetroceder.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

Comment: Y por ejemplo si estoy en hipotético fragmento 5 y quisiera ir al fragmento 3? Debería usar la opción de agregar otro binding.btnRetroceder.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.volver)? o usar  el popBackStack() de alguna forma?

Comment: `popBackStack()` siempre te va a llevar al fragment anterior. Si quieres retorceder más de una pantalla debes crear una acción y navegar usando su id. Probablemente también quieras agregarle un `popUpTo`, lee el enlace que dejé en la respuesta para entender como utilizarlo.